# Micrometer collection metric with pagination

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

I would like to create a metric that represents a list of groups. The group contains a name and the count of elements.

```
   public class GroupMetric{
      String name;
      int count;
   }
```

This metric is intended to be provided via a Rest API. The GroupMetric objects are already created and the data are set.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to display such a collection list of groups with one metric or is a metric required for each group?
2. How can I query the metric from the MeterRegistry?
3. Is it possible to use pagination, because the GroupMetric objects can be greater than 100.000

The output should look like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "group1",
            "count": "10000"
        },
        {
            "name": "group2",
            "count": "54"
        },
        {
            "name": "group3",
            "count": "122"
        }
    ],
    "totalItems": 3,
    "currentPage": 0,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "itemCount": 3
}
```

Currently using spring boot and micrometer.

Does anyone have experience or a good idea how to implement this?

Comment: What backend are you using for the data store? Also what do you mean by 'pagination'? You want the metrics endpoint to paginate? Sounds like you want to create a `gauge` for each group with a 'tag' of 'name' with the count.

Comment: Backend would be Application Insight or Promotheus. But i see in the API there is no possibility to read/get the metrics from remote. The Search API is just in memory, correct?

Ok yes i need a "flatten" list so for every group 1 gauge and then i have to collect them.

No not the metrics endpoint. I have an own endpoint where you can just collect all group metrics. Thats the idea

Comment: Prometheus will handle scraping the metrics from a Prometheus endpoint. Keep in mind that 1,000-5,000 metrics is typical. Having 100,000 metrics means your cardinality is too high. Micrometer metrics are intended for aggregate measurements, not individual ones.